# consulta MySQL darle prioridad a un LIKE

Tags: mysql

les escribo porque me gustaría hacer una consulta en MySQL dándole prioridad a un LIKE.
ej: Tengo un buscador donde ponen "Casa vieja"... y busco en los campos tema, documento y numero la palabras "casa vieja", "casa" y "vieja" sin un ORDER BY

Lo que quiero lograr es ordenar la consulta que primero me muestre las coincidencia en "Casa vieja" luego las de "casa"  y luego las de "vieja", se puede hacer en una consulta?

Ejemplo de la consulta que hago en este caso:

```
SELECT * FROM documentos WHERE (tema LIKE '%Casa vieja%' OR documento LIKE 
'%Casa vieja%' OR numero LIKE '%Casa vieja%' OR tema LIKE '%Casa%' OR 
documento LIKE '%Casa%' OR numero LIKE '%Casa%' OR tema LIKE '%vieja%' OR 
documento LIKE '%vieja%' OR numero LIKE '%vieja%' )
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

que tal porque no al final de tu consulta incluyes el order by (campo1, campo2,camop3)

Comment: Gracias por tu repuesta! pero eso lo que hace es que me ordene alfabeticamente... no por coincidencias como lo necesito.

Answer (score 1):

¿Te servirá algo como un UNION?

```
SELECT * 
FROM documentos 
WHERE 
    tema LIKE '%Casa vieja%'
    OR documento LIKE '%Casa vieja%' 
    OR numero LIKE '%Casa vieja%'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM documentos
WHERE
    tema LIKE '%Casa%'
    OR documento LIKE '%Casa%' 
    OR numero LIKE '%Casa%'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM documentos
WHERE
    OR tema LIKE '%vieja%' 
    OR documento LIKE '%vieja%' 
    OR numero LIKE '%vieja%'
```

**Actualización 1**.

Viendo este post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609166/mysql-order-by-like?noredirect=1&lq=1

Me inspiré para hacer algo de este estilo.

```
SELECT * 
FROM documentos 
ORDER BY
    tema LIKE '%Casa vieja%' DESC,
    documento LIKE '%Casa vieja%' DESC,
    numero LIKE '%Casa vieja%' DESC,
    tema LIKE '%Casa%' DESC,
    documento LIKE '%Casa%' DESC,
    numero LIKE '%Casa%' DESC,
    tema LIKE '%vieja%' DESC,
    documento LIKE '%vieja%' DESC,
    numero LIKE '%vieja%' DESC
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a intentar con UNION

Comment: Espera, ve mi actualización. Es más general.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar Order By Fields, y especificar el orden en que necesitas esa información, en el siguiente link puedes encontrar más sobre el tema: [Order by field](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/mysql-ordering-results-by-specific-field-values/)

El siguiente código

```
SELECT name, species FROM `pet`
ORDER BY FIELD(species, 'dog','cat','snake','bird'), name ASC
```

Tendría una salida como la siguiente

```
|name     | species|
|Bowser   |  dog   |
|Buffy    |  dog   |
|Fang     |  dog   |
|Claws    |  cat   |
|Fluffy   |  cat   |
|Slim     |  snake |
|Chirpy   |  bird  |
|Whistler |  bird  |
```

Comment: por favor, dale editar y añade lo relevante de ese link en tu respuesta, pues solo poner enlaces se considera de baja calidad

Comment: @maucano Está super útil esa opción, pero creo que no funciona con wildcards :(

Comment: @mrc_es ¿pero está bien no? lo que podría hacer el sería algo como
-----
Order By FIELD (documento.tema, 'Casa', 'Casa Vieja', 'Vieja');
-----
A menos que te refieras a otra cosa jaja :P

Comment: @MauCano de hecho me refiero a insertar wildcards, algo como `ORDER BY FIELD(tema, "%casa vieja%", "%casa%")`. Ve la actualización de mi respuesta. Deja investigo más de `FIELD` que se ve prometedor.